# How to determine if a char has white space?

Tags: c

Lets say we have `char *str = "123 467";` Is there something like isdigit() for numbers to return a boolean value?

Comment: By the way, converting a litteral to a `char *` is a deprecated conversion, and is potentially unsafe. Use `const char *` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about isspace()?  This will tell you if a char is a white space character.

It is included in ctype.h